# sbt exclude artifact with 'exclude'

Tags: scala, sbt, sbt-assembly

I am looking to exclude artifact from jar with sbt pattern in build.scala. I have seen few posts but have no clue still.

```
  [error] deduplicate: different file contents found in the following:
  [error] /home/me/.ivy2/cache/com.datastax.spark/spark-cassandra-connector_2.10/jars/spark-cassandra-connector_2.10-2.0.3.jar:org/objectweb/asm/signature/SignatureWriter.class
  [error] /home/me/.ivy2/cache/org.ow2.asm/asm/jars/asm-5.0.4.jar:org/objectweb/asm/signature/SignatureWriter.class
  [error] deduplicate: different file contents found in the following:
  [error] /home/me/.ivy2/cache/com.datastax.spark/spark-cassandra-connector_2.10/jars/spark-cassandra-connector_2.10-2.0.3.jar:org/objectweb/asm/signature/SignatureVisitor.class
  [error] /home/me/.ivy2/cache/org.ow2.asm/asm/jars/asm-5.0.4.jar:org/objectweb/asm/signature/SignatureVisitor.class
```

I'd like to exclude `org/objectweb/asm`

I tired

```
libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
...
"com.datastax.spark"  %% "spark-cassandra-connector"  % "2.0.3"  exclude("org.objectweb", "asm"), 
...)
```

Answer (score 2):

you should have done it like

```
libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
...
"com.datastax.spark"  %% "spark-cassandra-connector"  % "2.0.3"  exclude("org.objectweb.asm", "org.objectweb.asm"), 
...)
```

you can also do it as

```
libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
...
"com.datastax.spark"  %% "spark-cassandra-connector"  % "2.0.3", 
...).map(_.exclude("org.objectweb.asm", "org.objectweb.asm"))
```

if you are using sbt 0.13.8 and above then you can do

```
libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
...
"com.datastax.spark"  %% "spark-cassandra-connector"  % "2.0.3", 
...)

excludeDependencies += "org.objectweb.asm" % "org.objectweb.asm"
```

Comment: What's the rule ? why `"org.objectweb.asm"` twice ?

Comment: Still have the same problem after `reload`,`update`,`assembly`

Comment: I was guessing the dependency you want to exclude is https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.objectweb.asm/org.objectweb.asm/3.3.1.v201105211655. is it not? did you try all the methods?

Comment: I want to exclude the `org.objectweb.asm` only from one artifact , let it be `spark-cassandra-connector` and keep it in another `org.ow2.asm`, I think two other methods will remove the `org.objectweb.asm` at all . Am I wrong ?